# NFS update on client if server side gets mount?

Tags: linux, nfs

I have the following export on the NFS server:

/mnt/pve/4bay 192.168.1.0/24(rw,async,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check)

On the client, I have this in fstab:

pve.lan:/mnt/pve/4bay /mnt/pve/4bay defaults,soft 0 0

Now, if I mount a disk to /mnt/pve/4bay on the server, I can't see the changes on the client automatically. Can this be done?

Comment: When you run mount command do you see the NFS mounted?

Comment: I mount on boot via fstab

Comment: NFS works with file handles. As your client already has a mount, it already has a valid file handle for the mount point. All further operations are based on the resolved file handle. Try to mount the new disk as a subdirectory.

Comment: What's the output from running `findmnt /mnt/pve/4bay` on the client?